# How can you extract separate labels in the pyradiomics extractor?

Tags: python

I'm currently using the pyradiomics toolkit to extract features from my data. In this example I have a mask which has 5 separate objects in it, so I also have 5 labels.

I use the following code to do so:

```
    image = sitk.GetImageFromArray(image)
    mask= sitk.GetImageFromArray(mask)

    extractor = featureextractor.RadiomicsFeatureExtractor()

    labels = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    for i in labels:
        results = extractor.execute(image, mask, label=i)
```

My code isn't fast because a for-loop runs over the extractor, so I'm looking for a way to extract all the features for all the labels and then select them afterwards, looking something like this:

```
results_label1 = results[1]
results_label2 = results[2]
```

Does anyone have any advice?

Thanks so much!